# NSRangeException when calling OADataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest POST

Tags: ios, oauth

Started communicating with web service API that implements Oauth.  Implemented OauthConsumer and started building and retreiveing data with GET methods.  All worked fine until I attemped a POST methods with XML body.
At first I started barking up the wrong trees until I discovered a few nuggets that helped me get a bit closer to resolving the issue

- I needed to set the Content-Type
- I needed to prepare the request before setting the setHTTPBody method

  ```
  OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                     consumer:consumer
                        token:accessToken
                        realm:nil
            signatureProvider:nil];


  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request prepare];

  [request setHTTPBody:[xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

  [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                   delegate:self
          didFinishSelector:@selector(apiTicket:didPostInvoice:)
            didFailSelector:@selector(apiTicket:didFailPostInvoice:)];
  ```

I then started getting a NSRangeException when calling fetchDataWithRequest.

How to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the problem is the `fetchDataWithRequest` calls the `prepare` method and this undoes all the good work leading up to fetching the data.  The solution was to create a fetchDataWithPreparedRequest method to ensure prepare is not called again

```
@implementation OADataFetcher
...

- (void)fetchDataWithPreparedRequest:(OAMutableURLRequest *)aRequest delegate:(id)aDelegate didFinishSelector:(SEL)finishSelector didFailSelector:(SEL)failSelector {
        [request release];
        request = [aRequest retain];
        delegate = aDelegate;
        didFinishSelector = finishSelector;
        didFailSelector = failSelector;

//      [request prepare];

        connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:aRequest delegate:self];
}

@end
```